# Is the Google OAuth Service for OAuth 2.0 free?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, next.js, google-oauth, next-auth, cost-management

I'm using NextAuth in my web app and I've implemented authentication using the Google OAuth 2.0 service as one provider.

This service is located at the `console.cloud.google.com` page of Google Cloud, in the section of APIs & Services > Credentials > OAuth 2.0 Client IDs

Since I only used Firebase, I have it not clear if this service charges after some period or if the service exceeds some parameters, and if it does, how costs are measured.

I tried the Google Cost Calculator, but there is a lot of services I was not able find it right.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about account management, including billing and pricing should be referred to the relevant vendor - Google in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using google identity plat form you can check price at [here](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/pricing).

It says it is free until MAU reaches 49,999.